# My for loop not reading all the elements in the list - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```
test_list = [5, 6, [], 3, [], [], 9]

for x in test_list:

    print(x)
    
    if type(x) == int:
        continue

    elif len(x) == 0:
        test_list.remove(x)
    

print(test_list)
```

Output :-

5
6
[]
[]
9

[5, 6, 3, [], 9]

As you can see in the output when I use my for loop, not all my elements are being read. It has skipped 3 and an empty list ([]) at the same time.
Why is this happening.

Comment: Never change the list you are iterating over.